# How to set up GIT as version control tool for a small team

Tags: eclipse, git

We are using Eclipse with a SVN client plug-in. This client needs a server running; what about Git? We need to work in a LAN environment without internet access. I have read some basic tutorials about using Git with Eclipse. If I got a Java project in my Git repository, how can I share it with my teammate?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can share your local repositories, I would suggest setting up a server. There many free alternatives like:

- gitlab (http://gitlab.org)
- gitorious (http://gitorious.org)
- gitolite (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)
- gitblit (http://gitblit.com/)

But IMO the **best one is [Atlassian Stash](http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview)** which for small team will cost you only $10.

Comment: note that you don't strictly *need* any extra software even if you want a server - you can just use git through http or ssh, or use an existing service like bitbucket.

Comment: existing service is not an option as stated in the question.

Comment: even though it is possible to use git through http you get infinately  more with any of the alternatives I mentioned.

Comment: yes, sure. Just that it's worth mentioning that you don't have to have 'em.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to share it, you need some way to access it from each other. Bitbucket is great for small teams who need private code.

If you are always using it from inside a LAN one of you should set up a shared section which you can all push your git changes too (a shared folder or shared drive is good enough) but i would recommend using github / bitbucket if possible

from a command line (can probably use it within eclipse too)

`git clone file:////192.168.1.100/code`

and then you can psuh and pull from 192.168.1.100/code assuming you have write permissions there

Answer (score 0):

if you're coming from subversion to git, you will be faced with the concept of local repository vs shared repository. You will be able to have a local repository on your computer where you can do as many commits as you want and then only push relevant changes to the shared repository (the one that your teammates will be able to see).

Here's an useful link on the possibilities to share a repository: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/ (ignore the last one, GITHUB, which will require internet access).

In your particular situation I would recommend sharing via SSH or via GIT daemon.

I also really recommend you to take a look on Eric Sink's book [here](http://www.ericsink.com/vcbe/). He's even offering hardcopies for free!

Answer (score 0):

as suggested you can run your own instance of gitolite or gitlab, but for a rudimentary solution i suggest you just check the following answer:

https://serverfault.com/a/113688/181010

basically you can use any folder as a shared repository as long as all users can access the files either locally or via ssh. that link discribes how to tell git to create its file with rights that are appropriate for usage by all users of one unix group (instead of only the single user owning the files).